# EF Core - Change column type from varchar to uuid in PostgreSQL 13: column cannot be cast automatically to type uuid

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

### Before:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

**Config:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //...

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```

This was the previous developer's code which resulted in GUID values for the column. But in C# I had to deal with strings, so I decided to change the model.

### After:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And I removed the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` code from Fluent API config.

I get the `column "Id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid` error.

I think the key in this message is the `automatically` word.

Now my question is that since the values on that column are already GUID/UUID, is there any way to tell Postgres to change the `varchar` type to `uuid` and cast the current string value to UUID and put it in the column? I'm guessing there should be a SQL script that can do this without any data loss.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `USING _columnname::uuid`. Here is an illustration.

```sql
-- Prepare a test case:
create table delme (x varchar);
insert into delme (x) values 
 ('b575ec3a-2776-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002'),
 ('4d5c5440-2776-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002'),
 ('b575f25c-2776-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002');

-- Here is the conversion that you need:
ALTER TABLE delme ALTER COLUMN x TYPE uuid USING x::uuid;
```

In your particular case:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "MyEntity" ALTER COLUMN "Id" TYPE uuid USING "Id"::uuid;
```

Btw, is your application the sole owner of the database model? If not then changing an existing table is a bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

You can use EF migrations for this task too. But you have to modify the generated migration code from

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "Users",
            type: "uuid",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "text");
```

to

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "Users",
            type: "uuid using \"Id\"::uuid",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "text");
```

The important part is: `type: "uuid using \"Id\"::uuid"`

Comment: I was looking for a way to add "using" to ef core migrations. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Michael. it's work for me if you add parenthesis
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "Users",
            type: "uuid using (\"Id\"::uuid)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "text");